# How can I force a blocking redraw of a UI element?

Tags: android, android-view, android-progressbar

I have a simple login page where the user enters a password, and that password is used to decrypt some data and create the main activity. The process of generating the key, calling the database and creating the main activity takes about 5 seconds so I want to show a progress wheel on the login screen immediately after the user clicks the login button.

Unfortunately since android handles UI refreshes in a non-blocking way the progress bar won't appear before the login function runs. I can't seem to find a way to force a blocking UI refresh for a view in Android. `invalidate()` and `postInvalidate()` both won't work since these simply notify Android that a redraw should happen at some point in the future.

Here is some sample code to explain what I'm trying to accomplish:

```java
        try {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            passwordEditText.setEnabled(false);

            Key key = doLogin(passwordEditText.getText()); // Long operation

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Key", key);
            startActivity(intent);

            getActivity().finish();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            passwordEditText.setError(getString(R.string.login_error));
            Log.e("Login", e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            passwordEditText.setEnabled(true);
        }
```

If it's not possible to override the default behaviour and force an immediate blocking redraw, then how best can I best implement a progress wheel while the `doLogin()` method runs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't seem to find a way to force a blocking UI refresh for a view in Android

Correct. That is not how the Android view system works.

> then how best can I best implement a progress wheel while the doLogin() method runs?

Have `doLogin()` be performed on a background thread. Update the UI on the main application thread when the background work finishes. Take into account that your UI may no longer exist (e.g., user pressed BACK) or may be replaced (e.g., user rotated the device or otherwise triggered a configuration change) while that background work is going on.

In modern Android app development, the three main approaches for doing this are to use a [`ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) and [`LiveData`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) along with:

- RxJava
- Coroutines (for app development in Kotlin)
- Your own background thread

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I've posted my solution based on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue. Here's my solution. It may be a little overdone, but I tried to make it easily expandable so it can be applied to other similar scenarios.

AsyncTask for login:

```java
    static class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, LoginTask.LoginTaskResultBundle> {

        private TaskActions mActions;

        LoginTask(@NonNull TaskActions actions) {
            this.mActions = actions;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mActions.onPreAction();
        }

        @Override
        protected LoginTaskResultBundle doInBackground(String... args) {
            try {
                Key key = doLogin();

                return new LoginTaskResultBundle(LoginTaskResultBundle.SUCCEEDED, key);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                return new LoginTaskResultBundle(LoginTaskResultBundle.FAILED, e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(LoginTaskResultBundle result) {
            if (result.getStatus() == LoginTaskResultBundle.SUCCEEDED)
                mActions.onPostSuccess(result);
            else
                mActions.onPostFailure(result);
        }

        // Result Bundle

        class LoginTaskResultBundle {
            static final int FAILED = 0;
            static final int SUCCEEDED = 1;

            private int mStatus;
            private Exception mException;
            private Key mKey;

            LoginTaskResultBundle(int status, Key key) {
                mStatus = status;
                mKey = key;
                mException = null;
            }

            LoginTaskResultBundle(int status, Exception exception) {
                mStatus = status;
                mException = exception;
            }

            int getStatus() {
                return mStatus;
            }

            Exception getException() {
                return mException;
            }

            Key getKey() {
                return mKey;
            }
        }

        // Interface

        interface TaskActions {
            void onPreAction();
            void onPostSuccess(LoginTaskResultBundle bundle);
            void onPostFailure(LoginTaskResultBundle bundle);
        }
    }
```

Sample call to the LoginAsyncTask:

```java
         new LoginTask(
                  new LoginTask.TaskActions() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPreAction() {
                        showProgressBar();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPostSuccess(LoginTask.LoginTaskResultBundle bundle) {
                        launchMainActivity();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPostFailure(LoginTask.LoginTaskResultBundle bundle) {
                        hideProgressBar();

                        passwordEditText.setError(bundle.getException().getMessage());
                        Log.e("Login", bundle.getException().getMessage());
                    }
                } )
                .execute(passwordEditText.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Only use `AsyncTask` from a retained fragment or some other stable location, and make sure that the UI elements that you are referencing are still good once your background work is over (e.g., the activity was not destroyed). You will note that I didn't list `AsyncTask` among the candidate solutions in my answer, as it is tricky to use correctly.